# What is the “abyss” in Luke 8:31?

Tags: jesus, luke, demons

What is the “abyss” that Legion was imploring Jesus not to command them to go away into in Luke 8:31?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the “abyss” in Luke 8:31?**

What is the “abyss” that Legion was imploring Jesus not to command them to go away into in Luke 8:31?

Strong's Concordance

abussos: boundless, bottomless
Original Word: ἄβυσσος, ου, ἡ
Part of Speech: Noun, Feminine
Transliteration: abussos
Phonetic Spelling: (ab'-us-sos)
Definition: boundless, bottomless

Usage: the abyss, unfathomable depth, an especially Jewish conception, the home of the dead and of evil spirits.

This abyssing of Satan is for a thousand years, (Rev. 20:2-3) during which time his influence on mankind will be no more than that of a prisoner in a boundless, bottomless pit, when Satan is abyssed, no doubt his angels also be hurled into the abyss with him.

Revelation 20:2-3  NASB

> "2 And he took hold of the dragon, the serpent of old, who is the
> devil and Satan, and bound him for a thousand years; 3 and he threw
> him into the abyss and shut it and sealed it over him, so that he
> would not deceive the nations any longer, until the thousand years
> were completed; after these things he must be released for a short
> time."

Isaiah 24:21-22  NET.    The Lord Will Become King

> 21 At that time  the Lord will punish  the heavenly forces in the
> heavens  and the earthly kings on the earth. 22 They will be
> imprisoned in a pit,  locked up in a prison, and after staying there
> for a long time, they will be punished.

**Conclusion:**

Abyss Luke 8:31: It is bottomless pit--"prison"  that Satan and his demons will be hurled into so that they will not be able to mislead mankind for a thousand years, after which time,  they will be released for a short period.

Answer (score 2):

The word ἄβυσσος (abyssos) only occurs twice (Luke 8:31, Rom 10:7) in the NT outside of the book of Revelation where it occurs another seven times, see Rev 9:1, 2, 11, 11:7, 17:8, 20:1, 3.

Its meaning in the NT is given by BDAG as:

> a transcendent place associated with the dead and hostile powers,
> netherworld, abyss.

In the NT it is the place from the devils and his minions rise (Rom 9:1, 2, 11, 11:7, 17:8) and into which the devil is finally thrown and locked up (Rev 20:1, 3).  Thus, the usage in Luke 8:31 is quite consistent with those in the Book of Revelation.

In the LXX it used of:

- the sea, Job 28:14
- deep water that covered the earth before creation week, Gen 1:2
- depths of the waters, Deut 8:7
- depths of the earth, Ps 71:20

The Pulpit commentary offers this few remarks:

> What is the abyss these rebel-spirits dreaded with so great a dread?
> It would seem as though, to use Godet's thought, that for beings
> alienated from God, the power of acting on the world is a temporary
> solace to their unrest, and that to be deprived of this power is for
> them just what a return to prison is for the captive. St. Mark's
> expression here is a curious one. He represents the spirits requesting
> Jesus "not to send them away out of the country." The two accounts put
> together tell us that these spirits were aware, if they were driven
> out of the country - whatever that expression signified, this earth
> possibly - they must go out into the deep, the abyss, what is called
> "the bottomless pit" in Revelation 9:1, 2, 11. Any doom seemed to
> these lost ones preferable to that. The whole train of thought
> suggested by the incident and the words of the Lord is very terrible.
> We see at least one reason why the first preachers of the Word have
> selected this exorcism. It indeed lifts a bit of the curtain which
> hangs between us and the night of endless woe!